# What is the necessity of weekly reports?

Tags: software-industry, management, scrum

I work in a small software company(14 engineers). I work as a team leader. I am having a little trouble, but I don't know if I am just on my concerns. So I cannot push my ideas with enough confidence. I hope you might help.

We are following weekly sprints on all teams. At the end of each sprint(on Friday) we are expected to prepare a weekly report. This report consists of which team member did what on that sprint, and what will s/he be doing on the next sprint. This report has its own word format, so there is no automated way to create these reports.

These reports are used by our general coordinator to tell the general situation to our boss each week. But the weird part is the boss is already at the office everyday, and he is an easy-to-communicate guy.

All the teams in company uses TFS, hence all work is actually trackable and planned already.

Therefore I find this report procedure highly redundant. Moreover sometimes the boss extract some unintended meanings from this reports. So these reports are not doing enough I believe. And they take at least an hour to prepare a report.

What I want to propose instead is to have weekly meetings to tell everything they want to hear.

- Can I be persistent on this suggestion?
- Or is there any use on these reports?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Ask your boss and the general coordinator what the point of the reports is :)

Comment: Well I know they don't have solid reasons to demand reports. So I'm considering to organize my colleagues against it. But I want to know if there are any beneficial use of these reports that even my boss and coordinator don't know about. Then I can suggest to use the reports on that way too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing proper **Scrum**. If you *were*, your Product Owner would *know* this data already and *might* prepare said report to his superior if needed.

There is no need for such a report in Scrum if everybody is doing his job.

You should talk to your Scrum Master about this. Maybe somebody is **not** doing his job? Make it a point in your retrospective meeting.

---

Alternatively, even without proper Scrum, you could suggest the use of a ticketing system. I think TFS can be used for this as well. Then those reports could be generated automatically for all people working in your company without the need for manually filled in text documents.

Comment: You are right we are not using the Scrum properly. At least on scrummaster level. And I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You could start by asking *why* those reports are needed and then suggest to do proper Scrum to give the people what they need.

Comment: For "order" they answer. The solution is me learning scrum thoroughly, then protest for it I guess.

Comment: Well, that's not an answer. If they want "order", they need to hire cops or accountants. "because I want it" is not something you can work with. Maybe you could figure out how to do it properly in Scrum (the book is only 100 pages long after all) and then suggest a better solution. Do you even *have* a Product Owner?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: So you have neither a Scrum Master *nor* a Product Owner?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54491/discussion-between-tolga-evcimen-and-nvoigt).

Comment: Real SCRUM is hard, and most companies are not able to do it.  You may want to look at a more loosely defined AGILE process.